# How is the capacity of link more for single network link

Tags: ethernet, transmission-line, network-interface, networking

In networks 
capacity_of_link = bandwidth*propagation_delay

My doubt is how can a same wire carry multiple signals? Is is because the wire is very long (still the wire can be either high or low). I can understand if parallel wires are the reason for increase in bandwidth and thus capacity increase.

Comment: "Capacity of link" is a strange phrase to use for that. What that equation actually gives you is the *delay* of the link in terms of symbols. For example, if you know that the time delay is 10 us, you can multiply this by the bandwidth of, say, 1 Gb/s to get the data delay of 10,000 bits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*the wire can be either high or low*

This assumption is wrong and is the source of your doubt. At high speed it's perfectly possible for one end to be high and the other low. A transition ("edge") from high/low takes time to propagate along a wire. It doesn't propagate at the speed of light either, but at a rate determined by the capacitance of the cable.

At high ethernet speeds it's perfectly possible to have multiple bits in flight along a cable.

Answer (score 0):

Ethernet standards use signal modulation to increase bandwidth without much frequency increase.

For instance 1000Base-T use PAM-5 modulation, it allows to transmit 2 bits at a time:

- 00 : -1V
- 01 : -0.5V
- Control : 0V
- 10 : +0.5V
- 11 : +1V

And for 10GBase-T a PAM-16 modulation is used, allowing around 4 bits to be transmitted at the same time.